# Linking my favicon.ico file, but something goes wrong

Tags: html, css

I uploaded my favicon.ico to /images/favicon.ico directory and I'm using this code to link it, but it doesn't show up on my website.
What am I doing wrong?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically speaking, favicon files should be in the root directory rather than a sub-directory, and if there's a favicon.ico file in the root directory technically you don't need to declare the path at all.

If you don't call the favicon `favicon.ico`, you can use that tag to specify the actual path (in case you have it in an images/ directory). The browser/webpage looks for favicon.ico in the root directory by default.

If you really want to keep it in a sub-directory, do this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```